# is it ok to abuse reinterpret_cast to convert an object to a derive class when it is not?

Tags: c++, testing

The following code compiles and works correctly, allowing me to gain access to protected fields of a class.  But is this an ok thing to do?  Feel dirty, but what do i know coming from Java:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  public:
    Base() : _f(42) {
    }
    int getF() { return _f; }
  protected:
    int _f;
};

class Der : public Base {
  public:
    void setF(int f) { _f = f; }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  Base *b = new Base();
  std::cout << b->getF() << std::endl;
  Der *d = reinterpret_cast<Der*>(b);
  d->setF(37);
  std::cout << b->getF()<< std::endl;
}
```

And if I am right and this is not ok, what is a good way expose internal encapsulated data fields of an object which normally don't need to be modified, but do need to be changed in testing?  The instance is created deep inside other components, so changing its type is not trivial.

Comment: While I can't see this blowing up it is undefined behavior.

Comment: See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) for a list of things you are allowed do with `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: There is no good way to break the law.

Comment: The answer probably depends a lot on how you define "ok".   (e.g. is it "ok" if it works on your current platform/compiler but might break in some future version of the compiler, or on some other platform?)

Comment: *"what is a good way expose internal encapsulated data fields of an object which normally don't need to be modified, but do need to be changed in testing?"* - There is no good way. You are supposed to test a class, or function, or module, or software component in general, via the interface it presents to the outside.

Comment: *"is it ok to abuse"* can rarely be answered with "yes" in programming.

Comment: @BaummitAugen sir, I am learning C++.  Don't talk to me about abuse not being ok.

Comment: "is it ok to abuse reinterpret_cast to convert an object to a derive class when it is not?" - only if you like your programs to have unpredictable behaviour and break randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you pretend an object is of type `Der` when it isn't, the behaviour is undefined. This could fail at runtime, and badly. Aside from the usual (specifically requesting your compiler to make invalid code crash), one way this could fail at runtime is if your compiler's optimiser assumes that since you are casting it to `Der*`, it must really be of type `Der`. If you then follow this by a call to a virtual function, the compiler may assume that since the dynamic type is already known as `Der`, virtual method lookup can be optimised away.

> And if I am right and this is not ok, what is a good way expose internal encapsulated data fields of an object which normally don't need to be modified, but do need to be changed in testing?

The `friend` keyword seems appropriate for that. This keyword makes private (and protected) members of a class available outside of the class. Since your `Base` class should know which class or function will be unit-testing it, it can grant access to that class or function.

```
class Base {
    friend class BaseTester;
    // ...
  protected:
    int _f;
};

class BaseTester {
  public:
    static void test() {
      Base *b = new Base();
      b->_f = 37;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    BaseTester::test();
}
```

---

For completeness, there are a few holes in C++'s access checks that you could abuse if for some reason you cannot modify `Base`. Here's one:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    // ...
  protected:
    int _f;
};

class BaseHack : public Base {
  public:
    static constexpr int Base::*_f = &BaseHack::_f;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  Base *b = new Base();
  b->*BaseHack::_f = 37;
}
```

Inside `BaseHack`, the expression `&BaseHack::_f` is allowed, because it names a protected member of a base class, accessed through its own class. But because `_f` is actually defined in class `Base`, its type is `int Base::*` rather than `int BaseHack::*`, and there is no rule preventing it from being used to access members of `Base`.